# How do you create a stand-alone interactive app with Houdini 18?

Tags: houdini

I am getting into Houdini and I see those vids of [interactive apps](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DbMlrigvVZk&t=64s) How do you package a houdini project ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Exporting animation from Houdini to Unity

Comment: Please use the edit link on your question to add additional information. The Post Answer button should be used only for complete answers to the question.